# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.setState')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I keep getting this error, and I don't know why, because everything I have tried don't work. Does anybody knows why this is not working and how it can work?

I get this undefined here:

```
this.setState({isAuthenticated: true})
```

Here is my code:

```
class Login extends Component{

        constructor(props){
            super(props);

            this.state ={
                email: '',
                password: '',
                isAuthenticated: false
            };

            function login(username, email){
                sessionStorage.setItem('loginSessionUsername', username);
                sessionStorage.setItem('loginSessionEmail', email);
                this.setState({isAuthenticated: true})
            }
        }

        render(){
            const isAuthenticated = this.state.isAuthenticated;
            if(isAuthenticated){
                return(
                    <div>
                        <Servicedesk />     
                    </div>
                )
            }
            return(
                <div id='Login' className='setVisible'>
                    <div>
                        <label>Emailadres</label>
                        <input type='text' placeholder='je email' onChange={ev => this.setState({email: ev.target.value})}/>
                        <label>Wachtwoord</label>
                        <input type='password' placeholder='je wachtwoord' onChange={ev => this.setState({password: ev.target.value})}/>
                        <br />
                        <button onClick={(event => this.handleClick(event))}>Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default Login;
```

Comment: can u please tell which line is this.state is undefined?

Comment: this.handleClick is not defined anywhere

Comment: this.setState({isAuthenticated: true})

Comment: This is because you have declared login as a function and it get executed before the component gets mounted which means there is no setState yet. Moreover you are calling handleClick form the button it will throw an error when you click the button.

Comment: Probably not related but I think you should have `login` defined as a function at the same level as `render` rather that inside the `ctor`

Comment: Move the `login` function outside the constructor.

Comment: The handleClick function works, but is not included here, because it does not affect the question :)

Comment: from where you are calling the login function? This will happened mostly the issue of forget to `bind` the function. did you bind it properly??

Comment: @JJNL77: You never call `login` in this code. Presumably that happens in `handleClick`. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: this is the handclick function:  this.handleClick = event => {
            var email = this.state.email;
            var password = this.state.password;
            SupportStaf.map(function (key){
                if(key.email === email){
                    if(key.password === password){
                        login(key.username, key.email);
                    }
                }
            });
        };

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use arrow function [(see the docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), that will bind the context to your function, like this:

```
const login = ( username, email) => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('loginSessionUsername', username);
        sessionStorage.setItem('loginSessionEmail', email);
        this.setState({isAuthenticated: true})
    }
```

Comment: This works for me! And this is the handclick function:  this.handleClick = event => {
            var email = this.state.email;
            var password = this.state.password;
            SupportStaf.map(function (key){
                if(key.email === email){
                    if(key.password === password){
                        login(key.username, key.email);
                    }
                }
            });
        };

Answer (score 2):

move your login function outside of your constructor.

```
class Login extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state ={
            email: '',
            password: '',
            isAuthenticated: false
        };
    }

        handleClick = () => {
            sessionStorage.setItem('loginSessionUsername', this.state.username);
            sessionStorage.setItem('loginSessionEmail', this.state.email);
            this.setState({isAuthenticated: true})
        }


    render(){
        const isAuthenticated = this.state.isAuthenticated;
        if(isAuthenticated){
            return(
                <div>
                    <Servicedesk />     
                </div>
            )
        }
        return(
            <div id='Login' className='setVisible'>
                <div>
                    <label>Emailadres</label>
                    <input type='text' placeholder='je email' onChange={ev => this.setState({email: ev.target.value})}/>
                    <label>Wachtwoord</label>
                    <input type='password' placeholder='je wachtwoord' onChange={ev => this.setState({password: ev.target.value})}/>
                    <br />
                    <button onClick={(event => this.handleClick())}>Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: not always necessary to move out of the constructor

Comment: Was just giving a tip man. Just a developer trying to help

Answer (score 0):

Modify the login function in the constructor to this.

```
this.handleClick = () => {
    sessionStorage.setItem('loginSessionUsername', this.state.username);
    sessionStorage.setItem('loginSessionEmail', this.state.email);
    this.setState({isAuthenticated: true});
}
```

Then modify the button jsx to this

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit</button>
```

Comment: `this.handleClick` really?
Do you know what actually `this` is?

Comment: Inside the constructor. not outside

Comment: this will throw error man. The method needs to be outside of constructor and inside the class.

Comment: It works @HarishSoni https://codepen.io/sadarshannaiynar/pen/MGBLRy Here's a codepen doing the same

Comment: `this` has a context inside the constructor so you can leverage this instead of declaring the property outside.